# Mock nested import in Python with MagicMock

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest, magicmock

My file (`ensure_path.py`):

```
import os

def ensure_path(path):
  if not os.path.exists(path):
    os.makedirs(path)
  return path
```

My test:

```
import unittest

from unittest.mock           import patch, MagicMock
from src.util.fs.ensure_path import ensure_path

FAKE_PATH = '/foo/bar'

class EnsurePathSpec(unittest.TestCase):

  @patch('os.path.exists', side_effect=MagicMock(return_value=False))
  @patch('os.makedirs',    side_effect=MagicMock(return_value=True))
  def test_path_exists_false(self, _mock_os_path_exists_false, _mock_os_makedirs):
    ensure_path(FAKE_PATH)
    _mock_os_path_exists_false.assert_called_with(FAKE_PATH)
    _mock_os_makedirs.assert_called_with(FAKE_PATH)

  @patch('os.path.exists', side_effect=MagicMock(return_value=True))
  @patch('os.makedirs',    side_effect=MagicMock(return_value=True))
  def test_path_exists_true(self, _mock_os_path_exists_true, _mock_os_makedirs):
    ensure_path(FAKE_PATH)
    _mock_os_path_exists_true.assert_called_with(FAKE_PATH)
    _mock_os_makedirs.assert_not_called()
```

This is giving the failed assertion `Expected call: makedirs('/foo/bar')` which I think makes sense because I think I'm mocking `os.makedirs` at the wrong level.

I've tried replacing `@patch('os.makedirs',` with `@patch('src.util.fs.ensure_path.os.makedirs',` and a couple variations of that but I get

```
ImportError: No module named 'src.util.fs.ensure_path.os'; 'src.util.fs.ensure_path' is not a package
```

Here is my `__init__.py` flow :

[image]

Is there an obvious fix I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your patch arguments need to be in the reverse order of the @patch decorators.

Comment: Oh man. You rock! Thanks dude, I'll accept in a couple minutes.

Comment: I wish I could remember where it said that in the documentation. I may have just seen it in some tutorial or in the comments of unit tests written by team members.